# Firestore - Updating documents from a POJO

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

The following way I can update fields in a document which I created from a HashMap:

```
public void saveNote(View v) {
    String title = editTextTitle.getText().toString();
    String description = editTextDescription.getText().toString();

    Map<String, Object> note = new HashMap<>();
    note.put(KEY_TITLE, title);
    note.put(KEY_DESCRIPTION, description);


    noteRef.set(note)
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Note saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.d(TAG, e.toString());
                }
            });
}

public void updateDescription(View v) {
    String description = editTextDescription.getText().toString();

    noteRef.update(KEY_DESCRIPTION, description);
}
```

How do I update fields when I save my document from a POJO and convert it back with `toObject`? Any examples?

Comment: hi florian, I cant understand your question. Please could you be more clear in your question?

Comment: What is the proper way of updating fields in a document when I am working with POJOs, not Maps.

Comment: Have you solved the issue?

Answer (score 2):

To make it understand, ill explain with a simple pojo class.

this is the sample pojo class

`User.java`

```
    public class User {

    String name;
    String mobile;
    String email;
    String address;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getMobile() {
        return mobile;
    }

    public void setMobile(String mobile) {
        this.mobile = mobile;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
}
```

I have one activity with single button and its code is as below

```
**Creating/adding new Document**

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    firebaseFirestore=FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            User user=new User();
            user.setName("ABCD");
            user.setAddress("Some Address");
            user.setEmail("some email");
            user.setMobile("mobilenumber");
            CollectionReference collectionReference=firebaseFirestore.collection("User");
            collectionReference.document("UserOne").set(user).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful())
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Document created/updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });

}
```

Now watch the code inside click listener of button. Here am creating a User object and adding values to its field using setters.

After that am initializing `CollectionReference` with the collection called `User` and adding document to that collection by 
  `collectionReference.document("UserOne").set(user).addOnCompleteListener()`

Here the document is `UserOne` and the object is `user in set()` method.  So this will add/create the document with name `UserOne` inside `User` collection.

[image]

> Now How to update fields of existing document?

**Method 1**
This method will update entire document with the object value you pass in `set()` method. You must know the `documentId` of the document which you want to update.
You can simply change the value of field by creating new object like this. Here am changing the value of `mobile` field.

```
 User user=new User();
            user.setName("ABCD");
            user.setAddress("Some Address");
            user.setEmail("some email");
            user.setMobile("0123456789");
            CollectionReference collectionReference=firebaseFirestore.collection("User");
            collectionReference.document("UserOne").set(user).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful())
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Document created/updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

now this will update the `mobile` field by value `0123456789`
[image]

**Method 2**

In this method you update particular field of your pojo class like this. Am updating `mobile` field with value `55555`;

```
  CollectionReference collectionReference=firebaseFirestore.collection("User");
            collectionReference.document("UserOne").update("mobile", "55555").addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Document created/updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }

            });
```

[image]

**Note:** Here you must know the `documentId` of document to update one of its fields

With this two method you must be able to update fields of your pojo class used in document. Hope this helps you.